# Read logs from one process during run of some command

Tags: bash, tail

I have some service which produces logs in the file `logs.log`.

I have some other command which interacts with this service. Let's say it is some `foo.sh`.

What I need, is to cut and save logs from `logs.log` exactly during `foo.sh` running. In other words I need that part of service's logs when it interacts with my `foo.sh` (so I don't care about `foo.sh`'s logs).

I would expect that this command will do the trick, but it continues reading the file when `foo.sh` has already finished:

```
> foo.sh | tail -f logs.log > foo_part.log
```

Is any nice way to perform this trick?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is made rather straightforward by sending your background processes to, well, the background:

```
foo.sh &
mypid=$!
tail -f /path/to/logs.log > /path/to/partial.log &
tailpid=$!
wait $mypid
kill -TERM $tailpid
```

`$!` captures the PID of the last job sent to run in the background, so we can `wait` on your script to finish, and then `kill` the `tail` process when we no longer need it.

Comment: awesome answer, learned something new today

Answer (score 7):

This version can do it too (i think):

```
( tail -f logs.log >foo_part.log &
foo.sh&
wait $! && kill %1 )
```

Note that %1 will hit the first background process in the subshell

Comment: Personally, I prefer to capture explicit PIDs rather than use the jobs roster, as an increasingly complex implementation of this might put more than one task in the background and `kill %1` may get the wrong target.

Comment: Because that i used the subshell parentheses so %1 will refer to the first job inside the subshell (but i am not so sure about this for all shells). Obvious your solution are more complete and functional for more cases, but i think it can do what the user needs.... Another problem is that my version needs at least the creation of foo_part.log with touch, your version do not.